# How to Implement On-Click Listener in Firebase-ui ListVeiw?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've been using ListVeiw implementation provided by Firebase-ui available in [this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database).
I intend to put a OnClick Listener for each row.When pressed it should change background color, But I could not find any way to get it done.Any help would be great.

-- **Done So Far**--

**Activity**

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Databse refernce
FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listveiw);


    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("l")
            .child("p")
            .limitToLast(50);


    FirebaseListOptions<ListItem> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ListItem>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.listitem)
            .setQuery(query, ListItem.class)
            .build();
    FirebaseListAdapter<ListItem> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ListItem>(options) {


        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ListItem model, int position) {
        String s = model.getName();
       TextView a= v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       a.setText(s);
       s=model.getWatch();
       a= v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
       a.setText(s);
       ImageButton b= v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
}
```

**ListItem.class**

```
public class ListItem {
private String name;
private String watch;

public ListItem(){}

public  ListItem(String name,String watch){
    this.name=name;
    this.watch=watch;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getWatch() {
    return watch;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setWatch(String watch) {
    this.watch = watch;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set click event like this in listView inside populateView(...)

```
mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra(TITLE, title);
                                        intent.putExtra(CONTENT, content);
                                        intent.putExtra(KEY, key);
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
```